# Partial '_widget.htm' not found ReportWidget OctoberCMS

Tags: php, octobercms

[image]

I have tried to create a RecordWidget to use on dashboard in OctoberCMS.
But i am struggeling with rendering the widget.htm.

The structure of filesystem is as below

```
plugins
 ds
  irental
   reportwidgets
    welcome
     assets
      css
     partials
      _widget.htm
    Welcome.php
```

_widget.htm:

```
<div class="report-widget widget-welcome">
    <h3>Test</h3>

        <div class="welcome-container">
            <div class="welcome-logo">
                <div class="oc-logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome-message">

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Welcome.php:

```
<?php namespace ds\Irental\ReportWidgets;

use Backend\Classes\ReportWidgetBase;

class Welcome extends ReportWidgetBase
{

    public function defineProperties() {
        return [
            'title' => [
                'title' => 'Test'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function init() {

    }
    /**
     * Renders the widget.
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return $this->makePartial('widget');
    }
}
```

Plugin:

```
<?php namespace ds\Irental; 

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerComponents()
    {
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }

    /*
    * Register report widgets
    */
    public function registerReportWidgets()
    {
        return [
            'ds\Irental\ReportWidgets\Welcome' => [
                'label' => 'IRental',
                'context' => 'dashboard'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

I have tried to follow the documentation at octoberCMS. https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/widgets#report-widgets
But I can't make it work. Does I miss some settings somewhere?

Comment: Don't see that you declared your namespace as it did in the tutorial.

Comment: @WKoppel he is making his own new widget from his plugin so namespace is based on his plugin name

Answer (score 2):

I guess your file structure is creating problem

> Wrong Class Location [ **your current structure of filesystem** ]

```
plugins
 ds
  irental
   reportwidgets
    welcome
     assets
      css
     partials
      _widget.htm
     Welcome.php     <- problem its inside `welcome` folder
```

so when your `Welcome.php` is one level deep it try to search from there `CLASS_LOCATION/welcome/partial/_widget.php` and it can not find it.
here CLASS_LOCATION is `welcome` folder

> Correct Class Location [ **Revised** ]

```
plugins
 ds
  irental
   reportwidgets
    welcome          <--
     assets            |
      css              |
     partials          |
      _widget.htm      |
    Welcome.php      <--  it need to be in same level
```

Now its correct so it can find partial on proper location 
`CLASS_LOCATION/welcome/partial/_widget.php`
here CLASS_LOCATION is `reportwidgets` folder

> **UPDATE**

Yes seems folder name you used is different from the class-name

[image]

> It will pick partials baed on classname converting it to lower and start search from class current location.

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: Upps. I discovered that I have added one space to much before Window.php file. It is on the same level as welcome in file structure. Have made the correction in the question.

Comment: hmm, if possible can you share your plugin with report widget only a zip file so i can look in to it, you can send it via email from my profile page :)

Comment: I discovered what the problem was. The ReportWidget Controller must have the same name as the folder where the partials _widget.htm lives.

So if the Reportwidget shall be named "MyReport.php". then the parent folder on the same level must also have the same name "myreport"

Comment: yes updated answer, i see that problem, i have keep previous answer may be it can help others and also posted new answer as update :). i am glad you got solution :)